# Putting two accounts in group not giving read access to group members

Tags: scp, group, chmod

I have an Apache based web site and am trying to allow the user to upload files to a drop box on one machine and then have them transferred to another.  So I form a group for two users: www-data which is the Apache web user and OtagoHarbour which has a key to transfer files from one machine to another.

The existence of the group and its members is confirmed thus.

```
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ egrep -i "www-OtagoHarbour" /etc/group
www-OtagoHarbour:x:1002:OtagoHarbour,www-data
```

However, this does not appear to give OtagoHarbour group permissions to a group owned by www-data.

```
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo ls -ld dropbox
drwx-wx-wx 2 www-data root 4096 2014-01-20 23:25 dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo chmod g+r dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo ls -ld dropbox
drwxrwx-wx 2 www-data root 4096 2014-01-20 23:25 dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ scp /var/www/dropbox/*.cel 192.168.1.6:/var/www/dropbox
/var/www/dropbox/*.cel: No such file or directory
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo chmod o+r dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ scp /var/www/dropbox/*.cel 192.168.1.6:/var/www/dropbox
whatever1.cel                    100%   11MB  11.3MB/s  00:01    
whatever2.cel                    100%   11MB  11.2MB/s  00:01    
whatever3.cel                    100%   11MB  11.2MB/s  00:01
```

So, despite www-data and OtagoHarbour being in the same group, g+r does not appear to give OtagoHarbour read access to a group owned by www-data (but o+r does).

Update

```
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo chgrp -R www-OtagoHarbour /var/www/dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo chmod o-r dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ sudo chmod g+r dropbox
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ scp /var/www/dropbox/*.cel 192.168.1.6:/var/www/dropbox
/var/www/dropbox/*.cel: No such file or directory
```

Update 2

```
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ ld
ld: no input files
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ ls -l /var/www/dropbox/*.cel
ls: cannot access /var/www/dropbox/*.cel: No such file or directory
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$ ls -l /var/www/dropbox
ls: cannot open directory /var/www/dropbox: Permission denied
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www$
```

Comment: Can you have your `OtagoHarbour` user run the `groups` command to make sure its group list includes `www-OtagoHarbour`? Group membership is set only by programs like `login` or `su`. A shell process (and any ordinary process spawned from it) that was created prior to `/etc/group` being updated won't have its groups changed.

Comment: @Mark.  Sorry about my slow reply.  The groups command showed both OtagoHarbour and www-data.  Thanks,

Comment: The problem is now fixed as outlined below.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users `OtagoHarbour` and `www-data` belong to `www-OtagoHarbour` group but `dropbox` directory isn't associated to `www-OtagoHarbour` group but to `root`.

Running command

```
sudo chgrp -R www-OtagoHarbour /var/www/dropbox
```

should fix the problem. With this change you don't need to keep the directory world readable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am still having problems as I have shown in the update above.  Thanks,

Comment: @OtagoHarbour Can you run the following commands as OtagoHarbour user and post the output here: 'id', 'ls -l /var/www/dropbox/*.cel' and 'ls -l /var/www/dropbox'

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  I have added the results in update 2 above.  Thanks,

Comment: It's working now.  Not sure exactly what fixed it.  I entered 'newgrp www-OtagoHarbour' then 'egrep -i "www-OtagoHarbour" /etc/group' returned 'www-OtagoHarbour:x:1002:OtagoHarbour,www-data'  then I enetered what you suggested and now it works.